# C Read a file from line x to line y

Tags: c, file

I am a beginner in C, and I would like to know if there is a way to read a file from one line to another for example from the 10th to the 20th.
I searched several times, and only found methods to read files line by line

Comment: [Programming means that sometimes you have to snap two blocks together](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090804-00/?p=17233).

Comment: As a beginner the simplest is to accept to use fgets and read line by line.

Comment: Read lines and discard them until you get to the desired line number. If you know by advance which is the maximum length of a line in your file, just call fgets() inside a loop to count/discard lines.

Comment: So, read the lines and ignore **up to 9**, print until 20th then close the file. And searching solution for this kind of trivial problem is kinda not effective in terms of learning.

You know for loop, you know condition, you know how to read line by line and you should be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

In most modern environments, the concept of a *line* is a convention whereby the character 0xa (ascii linefeed) denotes the end of a line.  Some CPM-derived systems have an anachronism which insists a 0xd (ascii carriage return) before the end of line character.   In even older environments, a *line* was a record of 80 bytes, corresponding to a solitary punch card.

In older, fixed record systems, line 10 was at offset 10*80 = 800 in the file.  In newer, *stream*-oriented io [ btw, newer here refers to the late 1970s ], you cannot calculate the line location without examining the file contents.  So, as others commented, you have to read and ignore the lines you do not want.   If it is critical for multiple queries of the same file, build an index of line locations and use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FIRST_LINE (3)
#define LAST_LINE (7)

#define FILE_NAME "lines.txt"

int main(void) {
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    FILE * file;
    int line;

    file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if ( file == NULL ) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    line = 0;
    while ( fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, file) != NULL ) {
        if ( ++line < FIRST_LINE )
            continue;
        else if ( line > LAST_LINE )
            break;
        else
            printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    if ( fclose(file) ) {
        perror("fclose");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

lines.txt:
I am a beginner in C, 
and I would like to know 
if there is a way to read 
a file from one line 
to another for example from 
the 10th to the 20th. 
I searched several times, 
and only found methods 
to read files line by line.
Know someone who can answer?

Comment: It does not genuinely help anyone to do their homework for them.